# How do I subscribe to React's global virtual events?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a standard or hacky way I can listen to all events for a given React application tree's events? E.g. all onClicks.

edit: No really, I want **all events**, not just specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no standard way to do this. To be precise you probably just want to listen for dispatches to synthetic event handlers, rather than listening to all events. For example just moving a mouse across the screen generates a stream of `mousemove` events.

To capture the event dispatches you would probably need to manually hack a listener into `executeDispatch` in https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.14.6/src/renderers/shared/event/EventPluginUtils.js

I'm hoping the your application for this is just for debugging legacy spaghetti code. Incorporating any kind of global listeners into production code would be asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You could just listen to events for the outermost container. That would include all the children. Then you would get the element under the location of the event.

Something like;

```js
let x = event.touches[lastTouch].pageX;
let y = event.touches[lastTouch].pageY;
let element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```